# How to display product attchements on ecommerce section of Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to find a way to display attachment added from products section to ecommerce/web. Found [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/fixed-what-is-wrong-with-this-code-73380) but not working. 
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: for debugging this problem ,use response.qcontext.update({'images':'images'}) and tell me  the result( i have tested the code  it worked at my end ) ,

Comment: What I did, added that class class website_sale_attachment end of the main.py of website_sale addon.Added <p><t t-esc="len(images)"/></p> in to views/templates.xml.I am really new to this and please let me what have I dont wrong? no errors but it is not showing on web page

Comment: have you restart odoo server  or not ??

Comment: yes several times and this is Odoo Enterprise not community

Comment: Finally it worked! But it is only showing no of files attached not a links to attached file
<t t-esc="len(images)"/>
Any idea?

Comment: try widget ="url"  , like <field name="images[0].url" widget="url"/>

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly.But added like this <t t-esc="len(images)" widget="url"/> and now when I inspect it shows like this
<a>1Product Attachment</a>
<field data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/t[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/field[1]" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="832" widget="url" name="images[0].url"></field>